# ¿Cómo eliminar Android-Studio de linux mint?

Tags: android-studio, linux, linux-mint

¿Como se puede desinstalar android-studio de linux mint?

Cometi el error de borrar las carpetas pero quiero hacer el proceso de desintalacion y me da error.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste a tu pregunta por favor, revisa [ask] y agrega mayor información a tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alberto Horacio Abitú normalmente para eliminar un paquete en linux haces lo siguiente

```
sudo">sudo apt-get remove <package-name>
```

Pero como has eliminado las carpetas directamente, no se si te dará error en la terminal por lo tanto te aconsejo que hagas lo siguiente:

```
sudo">sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
```

Al realizar un purge lo que hace es desinstalar el paquete y a la vez purgarte los paquetes dañados de esta manera de lo dejara todo limpio y funcionando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono de 10 thank you